# terminal appears on hotkey but command not executed

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Me being the lazy bum that I am, wanted to make youtube-dl (the script that downloads youtube videos) execute upon pressing a hotkey for the current link in clipboard. In my keyboard shortcuts i made:

```
gnome-terminal -e  "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 $(xclip -o)"
```

This command works if i enter it into a seperate terminal, but when i execute the hotkey, the terminal appears for <1 second, and the script does not execute.

Can anyone point me as to where im going wrong? :)

Comment: probably `$(xclip -o)` doesn't get substituted. Try `gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 $(xclip -o)"`

Comment: It works! thanks so much! :) I'll be happy to accept your answer as best if you post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As command substitutions are performed by the shell, you have to execute your command as an argument to the shell:

```
gnome-terminal -x /bin/sh -c "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 $(xclip -o)"
```